# error occurred system.web.httpexception was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am trying to display uploaded files in datagridview but it is giving error as 
system.web.httpexception was unhandled by user code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Name">
<ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("File") %>' CommandName="Download" Text='<%# 
Eval("File") %>'></asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'File'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not have File column exist in the result set. Check the result set in debug mode